# Python run script for every entry in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to write a simple python programme that uses the tweepy API for twitter and wget to retrieve the image link from a twitter post ID (Example: twitter.com/ExampleUsername/**12345678**), then download the image from the link. The actual programme works fine, but there is a problem. While it runs FOR every ID in the dictionary (if there are 2 IDs, it runs 2 times), it doesn't use every ID, so the script ends up looking at the last ID on the dictionary, then downloading the image from that same id however many times there is an ID in the dictionary. Does anyone know how to make the script run again for every ID?

tl;dr I want the programme to look at the first ID, grab its image link, download it, then do the same thing with the next ID until its done all of the IDs.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import tweepy #https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy
import wget


#Twitter API credentials
consumer_key = "nice try :)"
consumer_secret = "nice try :)"
access_key = "nice try :)"
access_secret = "my, this joke is getting really redundant"

def get_all_tweets():
        #authorize twitter, initialize tweepy
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
        api = tweepy.API(auth)

        id_list = [1234567890, 0987654321]
        # Hey StackOverflow, these are example ID's. They won't work as they're not real twitter ID's, so if you're gonna run this yourself, you'll want to find some twitter IDs on your own

# tweets = api.statuses_lookup(id_list)
        for i in id_list:
            tweets = []
            tweets.extend(api.statuses_lookup(id_=id_list, include_entities=True))
            for tweet in tweets:
                spacefiller = (1+1)
                # this is here so the loop runs, if it doesn't the app breaks 
            a = len(tweets)
            print(tweet.entities['media'][0]['media_url'])
            url = tweet.entities['media'][0]['media_url']
            wget.download(url)
get_all_tweets()
```

Thanks,
~CS

Comment: You have a loop `for tweet in tweets:` but you don't do anything in that loop. At the end, `tweet` is the last tweet in the list and that's the only one you use in `print(tweet.entities['media'][0]['media_url'])`. Should that work be done in the loop?

Comment: You enumerate ids in `for i in id_list:` but then you use the full list each time in `tweets.extend(api.statuses_lookup(id_=id_list, include_entities=True))`. Is that on purpose?

Comment: @tdelaney it is not. I honestly have no clue what I'm doing here since I'm not very good at coding, I just cobbled this together using the documentation, some example code I found on GitHub, and Trial&Error :^) (and a past issue i posted on SO that got merged)

Comment: @tdelaney i put the code in the loop and it works! ..almost. I have 2 IDs for my test, and it's downloading both the images, but because there's 2 IDs in the list, it's downloading them both twice. Should I remove the `for i in id_list`?

Comment: I don't know the API but if its working with the `id_list` and you getting everything twice, then yes, remove that outer loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! 
I knew that loop was being used for something...

I moved everything from `a = len(tweets` to `wget.download(url)` into the `for tweet in tweets:` loop, and removed the `for i in id_list:` loop.

Thanks to tdelany this programme works now! Thanks everyone!

Here's the new code if anyone wants it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import tweepy #https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy
import wget


#Twitter API credentials
consumer_key = "nice try :)"
consumer_secret = "nice try :)"
access_key = "nice try :)"
access_secret = "my, this joke is getting really redundant"

def get_all_tweets():
        #authorize twitter, initialize tweepy
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
        api = tweepy.API(auth)

        id_list = [1234567890, 0987654321]
        # Hey StackOverflow, these are example ID's. They won't work as they're not real twitter ID's, so if you're gonna run this yourself, you'll want to find some twitter IDs on your own

        tweets = []
        tweets.extend(api.statuses_lookup(id_=id_list, include_entities=True))
        for tweet in tweets:
            a = len(tweets)
            print(tweet.entities['media'][0]['media_url'])
            url = tweet.entities['media'][0]['media_url']
            wget.download(url)
get_all_tweets()
```

Answer (score 0):

One strange thing I see is that the variable i declared in the outer loop is never used after on. Shouldn't your code be

```
 tweets.extend(api.statuses_lookup(id_=i, include_entities=True))
```

and not id_=id_list as you wrote?

Comment: returns with
```File "twitterbot4.py", line 35, in <module>
    get_all_tweets()
  File "twitterbot4.py", line 28, in get_all_tweets
    tweets.extend(api.statuses_lookup(id_=i, include_entities=True))
  File "/home/conner/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 96, in statuses_lookup
    return self._statuses_lookup(list_to_csv(id_), include_entities,
  File "/home/conner/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/utils.py", line 36, in list_to_csv
    return ','.join([str(i) for i in item_list])
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```